# need help configuring python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

***what ive been doing:***
ive been reading a lot on the documentation on boto3 but im still struggling to get it working the way i am wanting as this is my first time using AWS.

im trying to use boto3 to access microsoft excel files that are uploaded to a S3 bucket... im able to use boto3.session() to give my "hard coded" credentials and from there print the names of the files that are in my bucket

however, im trying to figure out how to access the contents of that excel file in that bucket...

***My end goal/what im trying to do:***
The end goal of this project is to have people upload excel files into the S3 bucket with zip codes in them(organized in the cells)... and then have that file sent to an EC2 instance to have a program i wrote read from the file one zip code at a time and process certain things...

any help is greatly appreciated as this is all new and overwhelming

This is the code i am trying:

```
    import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='put key here',
    aws_secret_access_key='put key here',
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket name')

for f in bucket.objects.all():
   print(f.key)
   f.download_file('testrun')
```

Comment: If you are able to print the names of the objects in the S3 bucket then you already have boto3 configured correctly. You just need to call the appropriate method now to read the object contents, or to copy the S3 object to a local temporary space and then read it like a normal local file. Please show the code you have so far, and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: just added updated code @MarkB

Comment: Please explain where exactly you are stuck. It looks like you haven't made any attempt to read the contents of the files yet.

Comment: thats where im stuck... ive read the documentation and watched youtube videos but my understanding of how this is suppose to function seems like its missing something. Ive tried the download file operation but it did not work... so if im able to print the names of the buckets then that means im in the right place...im confused as to how to select it and then read whatever contents are in the excel files "cells" @MarkB

Comment: "Ive tried the download file operation but it did not work" then that sounds like where you are stuck. You need to include the code you used in this attempt in your question, as well as any error messages you received.

Comment: added the code im using to try and download file.. the error im getting is "AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'download_file'" @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the boto3 resource API instead of the client API, you should be calling the `Object.download_file` [method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_file) inside the `for` loop, like so:

```
for f in bucket.objects.all():
    print(f.key)
    f.download_file('the name i want it to be downloaded as')
```

Comment: ive added that code and put it in the edited post up top.. the error i am getting now is AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'download_file' @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
for f in bucket.objects.all():
    obj = bucket.Object(f.key)
    with open(f.key, 'wb') as data:
        obj.download_fileobj(data)
```